# How can I setup my code to have different modules implementing the same functions, that can be accepted as a param

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make my rust project more modular, where I have different integrations that should implement certain functions and have certain fields, along with additional ones specific to that integration. How can I make it so that a function parameter or struct field can accept any integration that implements the required functions?

Currently I'm using enums to do this, but the code is a bit sloppy.

```rust
enum SocialIntegration {
    Facebook(FacebookIntegration),
    Twitter(TwitterIntegration),
}

struct FacebookIntegration {
    pub username: String,
    pub url: String,
}

impl FacebookIntegration {
    pub fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult> {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct TwitterIntegration {
    pub username: String,
    pub url: String,
    following_list: Vec<String>,
}

impl TwitterIntegration {
    pub fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult> {
        todo!()
    }
}

struct IntegrationHelper {
    integrations: Vec<SocialIntegration>,
}

impl IntegrationHelper {
    pub fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult> {
        for integration in self.integrations {
            match integration {
                SocialIntegration::Facebook(integration) => integration.search(query),
                SocialIntegration::Twitter(integration) => integration.search(query),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Coming from typescript, and previously used just an interface, and then creating a class implementing the interface. I couldn't find anything quite similar in Rust, or figure out a combination of things to use to achieve a similar result in Rust.

Comment: Have you read about [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)?

Comment: *"previously used just an interface... I couldn't find anything quite similar in Rust"* - If you haven't already, I encourage you to read through the Rust Book, in particular it has a section on [Traits: Defining Shared Behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in other languages are analogous to [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html) in Rust. You can create a `SocialIntegration` trait:

```rust
trait SocialIntegration {
    fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult>;
}
```

And implement twice:

```
impl SocialIntegration for FacebookIntegration {
    fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl SocialIntegration for TwitterIntegration {
    fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Inside `IntegrationHelper` you can then store boxed [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html). This will let you store both facebook and twitter objects in the same vector and perform dynamic dispatch when calling their `search` methods.

```rust
struct IntegrationHelper {
    integrations: Vec<Box<dyn SocialIntegration>>,
}

impl IntegrationHelper {
    pub fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Vec<SearchResult> {
        let mut results = Vec::new();
        for integration in &self.integrations {
            results.append(&mut integration.search(query));
        }
        results
    }
}
```